# Is not-display of areas partially out of the plot limits ggplot2 and geom_area desired behavior or a bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following code, not all areas are shown in the plot called `gg2`. This seems odd to me. I guess it is due to numerical imprecision in combination with the `ylim` operand, however, it seems odd to me. Is this a bug or desired behavior?

Thanks and best greetings,
Sebastian

```
library('ggplot2')
library('magrittr')
library('tibble')
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')

squeeze <- function(x, min_value = 0, max_value = 1) {
  pmin(max_value, pmax(min_value, x))
}

par_values <- 0.1 * 2^(-3:3)

result <- expand_grid(beta = par_values, 
                      gamma = par_values) %>%
  mutate(S = squeeze(gamma / beta),
         I = squeeze((beta - gamma) / beta))

result_long <- result %>% pivot_longer(cols = c('S', 'I'))

(gg1 <- result_long %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = beta, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_area() +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(gamma)))

(gg2 <- gg1 + ylim(0, 1))

(gg3 <- gg1 + ylim(0, 1.001))
```

Here the output of `sessionInfo()`:

R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.2

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_1.2.1    dplyr_1.0.10   tibble_3.1.8   magrittr_2.0.3 ggplot2_3.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rstudioapi_0.14  tidyselect_1.2.0 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_2.0-3 R6_2.5.1         rlang_1.0.6      fansi_1.0.3      tools_4.2.1      grid_4.2.1       gtable_0.3.1     utf8_1.2.2
[12] cli_3.6.0        DBI_1.1.3        withr_2.5.0      ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1 lifecycle_1.0.3  farver_2.1.1     purrr_1.0.1      vctrs_0.5.1      glue_1.6.2       labeling_0.4.2
[23] compiler_4.2.1   pillar_1.8.1     generics_0.1.3   scales_1.2.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3

Comment: I just found something useful in the help page of `ylim`:
"By default, any values outside the limits specified are replaced with NA."

However, the behavior still seems odd to me since `sums <-  result_long %>% group_by(beta, gamma) %>% summarize(sum_SI = sum(value))
` does not show any coordinates that are outside the specified limits. 
I think it is a numerical problem, however, maybe ggplot2 should increase the region by a safety margin (e.g. 0.1 percent at each side) before cropping / not showing areas?

Comment: I understand the problem. Without deep-diving the problem, I suspect it may be related to floating-point comparisons (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272). If you change to `gg1 + ylim(0, 1 + 1e-10)`, it does not clip the graph. If what I suspect is true, it's not technically a bug in ggplot2 or R, mostly a concern with how floating-point comparison is made. (If I'm wrong, I hope somebody will offer an alternate theory :-)

Comment: FYI, "safety margin" perhaps, but the safety margin referred to as `expand=` (in the `scale_*` functions) isn't responsible for the data-clipping itself.

Comment: I think the `stat = "align"` default might contribute to some imprecision. If you use `geom_area(stat = "identity")`, it renders just fine for me.

Comment: It definitely seems like a floating point math thing or perhaps when stacking it's something that factors in some extra y value stuff?  Maybe the second thing stacked on top does not have it's "0" starting at the max value for the bottom piece, so it actually "starts" one pixel above that y value?  In any case, the "fix" is also to use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1))`, since `coord_cartesian()` does not remove the values outside of the limits, it just "zooms in".  `ylim()` Zooms in too, but discards data outside of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input!

My take-home-messages:

- I agree that the issue is probably due to floating point comparisons
- `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1))` definitely solves the problem!

Best greetings,
Sebastian